# Time series data visualization

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have two different data sources that I would want to use for my application

> 1) Time series data on a road network
>
> 2) Spatial data of the road network

In essence I would want to combine both the information and build visualizations. For example to show variation of speed with time on a particular road using a time slider.

To do this I created a view joining the two tables using sdetable tool and built a layer using the view. But for some reason I am not able to host it as a service.

Please do suggest if there are better ways to do it?

Comment: For reference, James Chesire's blog [spatial analysis](http://spatialanalysis.co.uk/2012/04/sensing-city-mapping-londons-population-flows/) has some really nice examples of visualizing road networks you may be interested in (both static and animations). I used to think roads were hard to visualize and should be avoided, as they did not have much  girth (and became convoluted when you  have many roads), he certainly proved me wrong though!

Comment: @Karthik: Check out [The TimeViz Browser](http://survey.timeviz.net/) for some inspiration.

Answer (score 2):

Awhile back I did simple unemployment data by county and time enabling layers to show changes by month. I created a map service and used the Esri javascript timeslider widget.

Couple Points of Troubleshooting:

- Make Sure Layers are Time enabled – calculate extent, then set intervals, make sure cumulative is NOT checked. These seem to need to get out of whack and need to be **constantly double-checked**.
- Make Query Table (instead of maybe sdetable tool) - My tables are linked in the ArcMap document with the respective feature classes that contain the polygons for the Counties with the "**Make Query Table" tool**. This can be found in ArcToolbox > Layers and Table Views. Be sure to use the **virtual object id** option when creating the table that links the polygons to the tables.
- **Clear the cache out of ArcServer** when changes are made to the map document and the service is restarted or recreated. Login to the ArcGIS REST API Admin. It usually can be found on your server at " http://[YOURSERVER]/ArcGIS/rest/admin"
- Btw about legends, maybe everyone know this by now, but if the Legend is not showing up – upgrade to at least sp2, otherwise your ArcGIS Server must be beyond the firewall to be able to connect to the ESRI servers to generate a legend